# how do i solve my gemfile error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, rubygems

I am updating my gemfile in order to deploy an app on heroku. this is the gemfile:

```
group development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group development do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

and this is the error:

There was an error parsing `Gemfile`: Undefined local variable or method `development' for Gemfile. Bundler cannot continue.

how can I solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You have forgot `:` (colon) in front of your group name. Instead you are trying to fetch value of variable/call function named `development`.

So your `Gemfile` should look like this:

```
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :development do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: yes you,re right. also second development should have been :production. thanks